# What does "Full Cowling" mean?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Cowling: the removable cover of a vehicle or aircraft engine.
So when Deku uses One for All-Full "Cowling" (as spelled in subs), does it refer to him removing the limiter on his power, or is it just mispronounciation ? Shouldn't it be "calling" instead?

Answer (score 1):

By using Full Cowl, Midoriya effectively uses One For All power on whole his body, rather than focusing on specific part.

This is most probably why this skill was called "Full Cowl". But it is not clear if author explicitly decided to use word "cowl", or rather didn't knew difference between it and some other english words with similar meaning (e.g. "coverage").

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the Japanese spelling:

ふる かうる (Furu Kauru)

- Furu --> Full
- Kauru --> Cowl

So it's actually right. Why he choose cowl? Well, you have to ask that to the mangaka. If I have to guess it's because his power covers his whole body.

Answer (score 0):

Something I would like to point out about the answers of @lentinant and @JustPlain.

Cowl : large loose hood, especially one forming part of a monk's habit.

"Cowling"  does not appear to be the - ing form of "cowl".  Both answers talk about "Full Cowl", not "Cowling".

Comment: I think the mangaka still tried to give coverage meaning so this applies to cowling as well.

Comment: Question is incorrect then. In both anime and manga, it is *Full Cowl*, not *Full Cowling*

Comment: @lentinant My sub group for the anime translates the name as "Full Cowling", so that could be where the OP's confusion stems from.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Crunchyroll's subs use "Full Cowling".

Comment: Actual spelling in anime is "Furu Kauru" (take a look at @JustPlain's anwer), and taken into account it is said along with "Wan Fō Ōru" (which is obviously "One For All"), I'm pretty sure it is japanese version of saying "Full Cowl".

Answer (score 0):

The full-cowl is a technique that exposes the quirk One for all to the entire body instead of focusing on the limbs in use. This was a part of a 2-part approach, first to limit using 100% of the quirk since it destroys his body with each use and to minimize the stress of the quirk and overall effectiveness.

As for the name I think the above answers are missing one thing and that's the overarching approach of the author(or mangaka).

Hero-Academia is all about the view of the superhero genre but from the perspective of a shounen. Therefore alot of references can be found here and there.

The concept of superheroes always have the idea of the cape & cowl, cowl in this context being the superhero costume, namely the mask. So the name Full cowling is essentially coating his body with his quirk like a suit of armor the same way superheroes always put on their costume before facing a villain or entering the scene of a crime.